# Display array of objects in two columns

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, html

I want to display array of objects in 2 columns. what is the easiest method to display the list as two columns?

```
const columns = [
    {
      subHeading: "A",
      subText: ["1", "2"]
    },
    {
      subHeading: "B",
      subText: ["3", "4"]
    },
    {
      subHeading: "C",
      subText: ["5", "6"]
    },
    {
      subHeading: "D",
      subText: ["7", "8"]
    }
  ];
```

Desired display on LWC Page:

```
A B
C D
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What part of that isn't working?  Please edit your question with more information about where you're stuck, or this question is likely to be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the question is a bit unclear , I'll try to provide a general approach.

We can achieve the desired result using a combination of `lightning-layout` & setting its container width as below :

```
<div class="container">
      <lightning-layout multiple-rows="true">
        <template for:each={columns} for:item="col">
          <lightning-layout-item key={col.subHeading} padding="horizontal-small">
            <p>{col.subHeading}</p>
          </lightning-layout-item>
        </template>
      </lightning-layout>
  </div>
```

CSS :

```
.container {
  width: 5vw;
}
```

You can try various combinations : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-layout-item/example